# Visual Studio Intellisense not Showing Events

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am writing a `VB.Net` program that uses the `TeamSpeak SDK`. It comes with `C#` examples and I have had no trouble converting them to `VB`.

However, I am trying to implement an event handler for a class called Connection. In `C#` when I hit a dot after the Connection variable, `Intellisense` shows a drop down with all options:

[image]

But when I work on the VB code (also in `VS 2017`), doing the same thing does not include events:

[image]

Note that the properties and methods shown are the same, just no way to select events. I am using the same "using" for `C#` and "Imports" for `VB` to reference `TeamSpeak.Sdk.Client`. I have a working VB program of several hundred lines that successfully implements the `TeamSpeak SDK`, so almost everything is working. Only now that I am wanting to add event handling have I run into a snag.

What should I try next?

Comment: VB.NET wires up event handlers in a different way, so it doesn't make sense to show them in intellisense **in the above context**.

Comment: Followup: I first implemented the AddHandler code suggested below. It compiled, but would never actually handle the event. I then saw the updated page with a link to the question specifically about event handling. I implemented the WithEvents/Handles code and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VB equivalent of this C# code:

```c#
myObject.SomeEvent += SomeMethod;
```

is this:

```vb
AddHandler myObject.SomeEvent, AddressOf SomeMethod
```

If you type the `AddHandler` keyword then Intellisense will show you available events.  In the case of the C# code, you can select an event in the same context as you can a property or method so it makes sense to show you them all together.  In VB, the only time you can use an event is in an `AddHandler` statement so you will only see events in that context.

Comment: Thanks a million. I would have been digging around in the dirt for a long time without your help. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to wire up events in VB.  The `AddHandler` method that @jmcilhinney shows, or by using the `Handles` keyword something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'do something useful with the button click
End Sub
```

If you do that, you will get Intellisense after the `Handles` keyword.  The arguments to your `Sub` are optional - if you aren't using `sender` or `e`, don't put them on the declaration

In order for that to work, the "Control" needs to be declared using the `WithEvents` keyword:

```
Public WithEvents Button1 As New Button
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. You and @jmcilhinney are a credit to the StackOverflow community.

Comment: The `AddHandler` method tends to appeal to traditional C# programmers (because it's so close to the `+=` method).  The `Handles` method tends to appeal to old-hand VB programmers, I believe it was how you wired things up in VB6.  The `Handles` method quickly grows on you if you get into VB for a while.

Comment: It's worth noting that, because C# only has one way of registering event handlers, creating an event handler in the WinForms designer will use that way but, even though `AddHandler` is the VB equivalent of that, creating an event handler in the designer in VB will use `WithEvents` and `Handles`. Generally speaking, the only reason to use `AddHandler` in VB is if you're creating objects at run time and thus cannot declare a field `WithEvents` to refer to it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `WithEvents`/`Handles` follows the variable while `AddHandler` follows the object. That means that assigning a new object to a field declared `WithEvents` will cause the new object to have its event(s) handled and the old to no longer have its event(s) handled.  On the other hand, using `AddHandler` registers an event handler on the specific object referred to at the time regardless of what happens to that variable afterwards.

Comment: @Flydog57, with regards to the down-votes, my guess would be that your answer doesn't actually address the specific question that was asked, even though it probably does address the root issue the OP was having.